# How can I detect an "unClick" in wxPython?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

I want to detect the difference of position between when I left-click in a panel and when I finish clicking (when the left button goes up after the click). I detect correctly the click and I know how to get the position of the mouse but I don't know how to detect when the click ends
This is how I associate the event of the left-click to the panel:

```
    x = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
    x.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(self.colores[aux2[1]]))
    x.SetMinSize((20,20))
    x.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.onClick)
```

This is the event handler:

```
def onClick(self, event):
        if (self.modo == 'jugando'):
            print('click')
```

And this is the output of the program:

```
click
```

So I know that I enter correctly in the handler but I don't know how can I detect when the left button of the mouse goes up afther this

Comment: [EVT_LEFT_UP](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.MouseEvent.html#wx-mouseevent)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
x = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
x.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(self.colores[aux2[1]]))
x.SetMinSize((20,20))
x.Bind((wx.EVT_MOUSE_EVENTS, self.onMouseEvent)
```

Event handling:

```
def onMouseEvent(self, event):
    if event.LeftDown():
        self.previous_position = event.Position
    elif event.LeftUp():
        self.current_position = event.Position
        ...
```